# Javascript multiple arguments and different data types in a function

Tags: javascript, arguments

I use `arguments` to allow multiple parameters in a function, like this:

```
  function foo(){
     for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        alert(arguments[i]);         
     }
  }
```

Passing `foo(1, 2, 3, 4)` = OK

But i need to know if it is possible to use various types of parameters, like `foo(1, "b", 3, "d")`. I get `Value is not what was expected` when i try.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes it's perfectly fine to pass different types, and the code you posted does not generate any error when you pass `(1, "b", 3, "d")`.

Comment: It works fine here. Could you provide a way to reproduce your problem?

Comment: It works see http://jsfiddle.net/LKZkH/

Comment: Just my Test.expect return that message, but now i see it works. Ty for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to handle this by yourself in your `foo` function, for example if you expect a `function` as first `argument`, you need to check if it is, at first of `foo`:

```
if(typeof arguments[0] != "function")
    throw new Error("unexpected argument")
```

or if you need a `number` as first argument:

```
if(typeof arguments[0] != "number")
    throw new Error("unexpected argument")
```

or try to convert it to a number first, like:

```
var o = parseInt(arguments[0])
if(Number.isNaN(o))
    throw new Error("unexpected argument")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also to add, a solid way to distinguish your function arguments between built in javascript object classes (Date, Array, RegExp etc) is to use comparisons like:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0]) === '[object Date]'
Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0]) === '[object RegExp]'
```

and so on, using a similar construct to @am1r_5h answer above